# Campo Date cadastrar date

Tags: mysql, asp, data

Tenho uma Tabela que um dos campos é tipo date. Na minha página inserir.asp quando digito a data por exemplo assim 10/07/2017 ou 2017-07-12 não salva no banco MySQL.

O erro que é mostrado é esse:

> Erro: [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.7.13-log]Incorrect date value: '' for column 'data_inicio' at row 1

Criei no código HTML uma função:

```
<%
Function InverteDataMySql(data_inicio)
if not isdate(data_inicio) then exit function
if instr(data_inicio, " ") > 0 then
hora  = split(data_inicio, " ")(1)
end if
InverteDataMySql = year(cdate(data_inicio)) & "-" & month(cdate(data_inicio)) & "-" & day(cdate(data_inicio))
if hora <> "" then InverteDataMySql = InverteDataMySql & " " & hora
End Function 
%>
```

Chamo a função aqui na página inserir.asp:

```
<tr>
    <td>Data Inicio:</td>
    <td>
     <input name="FormDataInicio" size="10" maxlength="80" value="<%=Response.Write(InverteDataMySql())%>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Mas não funciona.

**Tudo foi resolvido no próprio SQL usando STR_TO_DATE**

O código ficou assim:

```
 "INSERT INTO tb_registros_para_controle(nome_livro, nome_autor, nome_editora, data_inicio, " 
sql = sql & " data_termino, data_paralisacao, "
sql = sql & " segunda_feira, terca_feira, quarta_feira, quinta_feira, "
sql = sql & " sexta_feira, sabado, domingo, observacao) VALUES ( " 
sql = sql & "'" & Request.Form("FormNomeLivro")                  & "', "
sql = sql & "'" & Request.Form("FormNomeAutor")                  & "', "
sql = sql & "'" & Request.Form("FormNomeEditora")                & "', "
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataInicio")     &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", "
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataTermino")    &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", " 
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataParalisacao")&"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", "
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataSegunda")    &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", "
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataTerca")      &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", " 
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataQuarta")     &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", "
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataQuinta")     &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", "
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataSexta")      &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", " 
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataSabado")     &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", " 
sql = sql & "STR_TO_DATE('" & Request.Form("FormDataDomingo")    &"','%d/%m/%Y')" & ", "
sql = sql & "'" & Request.Form("FormNomeObservacao") & "' " 
sql = sql & ")"
```

Comment: O formato correto é `AAAA-MM-DD`. Você esta colando a data neste formato e entre aspas?

Comment: David, obrigado pela atenção, mas desculpe, não estou entendendo.

Comment: Complementando: David, obrigado mesmo pela atenção, Com relação a sua pergunta não entendi, desculpe. Não consigo encontrar um exemplo HTML/ASP para gravar uma data no campo date ou datetime no banco de dados no MySQL. Acredito que estou errando em chamar a função que o Gustavo me sugeriu. No livro que estou estudando só exemplo de salvar, alterar e excluir campo texto. David, estou lutando há dias para aprender como salvar, alterar um registro no banco de dados MySQL interagindo HTML com ASP. Mais uma vez obrigado pela sua atenção.